# Drop parsed element in parsy parser combinator?

Tags: python, parsing

I wonder if it possible (or maybe a ReallyBadIdea?) to parse, then just ignore the parsed element when building a parser with the python parer combination parsy? The input is a long text, there are two kinds of patterns that are interesting and the rest is "noise", identified as such one character at a time.

I can nearly get what i want by defining noise as
`noise = any_char.result(None)`
and then using `filter` to get rid of the None elements in the parsed result, leaving just the interesting parts. I'm basically wondering if it is possible to get a cleaner solution by not having to create and then filter out the Nones.